# SQL pivot table on text value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I am trying to pivot the following set of data in SQL.

```
SELECT  ParticipantID,
        ContactReasonTypeID,
        Completed = CASE WHEN Returned IS NOT NULL
                        THEN    'Completed'
                        ELSE 'Not completed'
                    END
FROM    ContactReason
WHERE   ContactReasonTypeID = 40 -- M4
UNION
SELECT  ParticipantID,
        ContactReasonTypeID,
        Completed = CASE WHEN Returned IS NOT NULL
                        THEN    'Completed'
                        ELSE 'Not completed'
                    END
FROM    ContactReason
WHERE   ContactReasonTypeID = 80 -- M8
```

Which gives the following result:

```
ParticipantID | QuestionnaireID  | Completed
1               40                 'Completed'
1               80                 'Not completed'
2               40                 'Completed'
2               80                 'Completed'
3               40                 'Completed'
3               80                 'Not completed'
4               40                 'Completed'
4               80                 'Not completed'
```

What I would like is for the results to be pivoted like so (where M4 is QuestionnaireID 40 and M8 is 80):

```
ParticipantID | M4           | M8
1               'Completed'    'Not completed'
2               'Completed'    'Completed'
3               'Completed'    'Not completed'
4               'Completed'    'Not completed'
```

I'm struggling on how to pivot the table. My current SQL is as follows and is resulting in errors. I've tried switching around the columns based on other posts but can't work out what is needed:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
    SELECT  ParticipantID,
            ContactReasonTypeID,
            Completed = CASE WHEN Returned IS NOT NULL
                            THEN    'Completed'
                            ELSE 'Not completed'
                        END
    FROM    ContactReason
    WHERE   ContactReasonTypeID = 40
    UNION
    SELECT  ParticipantID,
            ContactReasonTypeID,
            Completed = CASE WHEN Returned IS NOT NULL
                            THEN    'Completed'
                            ELSE 'Not completed'
                        END
    FROM    ContactReason
    WHERE   ContactReasonTypeID = 80
) AS tbl
PIVOT (
    MAX(Returned)
    FOR ContactReasonTypeID IN ([M4],[M8])
) AS pvt
ORDER BY ParticipantID
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the command [PIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017) for this

```
DECLARE @t table(ParticipantID INT, QuestionnaireID INT, Completed varchar(20))
INSERT @t values
(1,40,'Completed'),(1,80,'Not completed'),(2,40,'Completed'),
(2,80,'Completed'),(3,40,'Completed'),(3,80,'Not completed'),
(4,40,'Completed'),(4,80,'Not completed')


SELECT ParticipantID, [40] M4, [80] M8
FROM @t
PIVOT
  (min(COMPLETED)  
FOR QuestionnaireID
  in([40],[80])  
)AS p
ORDER BY ParticipantID
```

Result:

```
ParticipantID   M4          M8
1               Completed   Not completed
2               Completed   Completed
3               Completed   Not completed
4               Completed   Not completed
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following code:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT CR.ParticipantID,
        (SELECT CASE
                    WHEN Returned IS NOT NULL
                    THEN 'Completed'
                    ELSE 'Not completed'
                END M4
           FROM ContactReason
          WHERE ContactReasonTypeID = 40 --M4
            AND ParticipantID = CR.ParticipantID) M4,
        (SELECT CASE
                    WHEN Returned IS NOT NULL
                    THEN 'Completed'
                    ELSE 'Not completed'
                END M4
           FROM ContactReason
          WHERE ContactReasonTypeID = 80 --M8
            AND ParticipantID = CR.ParticipantID) M8
FROM    ContactReason CR
WHERE   CR.ContactReasonTypeID IN (40, 80) -- M4 and M8
```

Comment: This approach worked well, however I marked the selected answer due to the use of pivot table.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this :

```
SELECT q.ParticipantID, 
                  CASE WHEN min(q.QuestionnaireID) = 40
                        THEN min(q.Completed)
                    END as M4,
                   CASE WHEN max(q.QuestionnaireID) = 80
                        THEN max(q.Completed)
                    END as M8
  FROM
(
SELECT  ParticipantID,
        ContactReasonTypeID,
        Completed = CASE WHEN Returned IS NOT NULL
                        THEN    'Completed'
                        ELSE 'Not completed'
                    END
FROM    ContactReason
WHERE   ContactReasonTypeID = 40 -- M4
UNION
SELECT  ParticipantID,
        ContactReasonTypeID,
        Completed = CASE WHEN Returned IS NOT NULL
                        THEN    'Completed'
                        ELSE 'Not completed'
                    END
FROM    ContactReason
WHERE   ContactReasonTypeID = 80
) q
GROUP BY ParticipantID;
```

Inside [***Demo***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/577d9/1), consider inner query q as `tab2`.