# SQL Server pivot text values

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I am practising pivot. And I have a table with Name and Occupation data (code to generate sample is below). I need to put Occupations in columns, and stack beneath each occupation, names. Null is fine.

I have seen a number of posts, and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52147382/sql-pivot-table-on-text-value) one is what I need, but once adapted to my data, it only pulls 1 row of data.

Here is the code to generate sample and actual pivot code. How can I correct this error?

```
declare @occupations table (ename nvarchar(10), occupation nvarchar(10) )
insert @occupations
values 
('John','Doctor'),('Mary','Doctor'),('Jack','Doctor'),('Anna','Doctor'),
('Jim','Singer'),('Kate','Singer'),('Helen','Actor'),('Paco','Singer')

SELECT [Doctor] Doctor, [Singer] Singer, [Actor] Actor
FROM @occupations
PIVOT
  (min(ename)  
    FOR occupation IN ([Doctor],[Singer], [Actor])  
  )AS pp
```

I get this result:

```
 Doctor Singer Actor
 Anna   Jim    Helen
```

There should be more rows to include all names. I.e. you can see in insert statement that there are 4 doctors, for example. So should be 8 lines with some nulls.

Comment: Does the occupation contains other values than Doctor, Singer and Actor ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to make your data horizontal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58605804/how-to-make-your-data-horizontal)

Comment: @xXx, no that post didn't answer it, it is a bit different and I actually needed to understand why my code didn't work, so from that post i wouldn't be able to figure it out. Thanks though, for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all rows, simply add a unique key like row_number()

**Example**

```
SELECT [Doctor] Doctor, [Singer] Singer, [Actor] Actor
FROM (
       Select *
             ,rn=row_number() over(order by ename) 
        from @occupations
     ) src
PIVOT
  (min(ename)  
    FOR occupation IN ([Doctor],[Singer], [Actor])  
  )AS pp
```

**Returns**

```
Doctor  Singer  Actor
Anna    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    Helen
Jack    NULL    NULL
NULL    Jim     NULL
John    NULL    NULL
NULL    Kate    NULL
Mary    NULL    NULL
NULL    Paco    NULL
```

Comment: thanks, that solved it. wish i also knew why - is it because MIN is an aggregate function?

Comment: @LanaB Happy to help,  PIVOT by default is an aggregation,  So is simply becomes a small matter to "feed" it a distinct key to aggregate.  In this case row_number()

Answer (score 1):

[SQL Fiddle Execution](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/514b2/4)

**MS SQL Server 2017 Schema Setup**:

```
create table occupations (ename nvarchar(10), occupation nvarchar(10) )
insert into occupations(ename,occupation)values ('John','Doctor'),('Mary','Doctor'),('Jack','Doctor'),('Anna','Doctor'),
('Jim','Singer'),('Kate','Singer'),('Helen','Actor'),('Paco','Singer')
```

**Query **:

```
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT *,
  (case when occupation like 'singer' then ename end) AS Singer,
    (case when occupation like 'doctor' then ename end) AS Doctor,
    (case when occupation like 'Actor' then ename end) AS Actor,
  ROW_Number() OVER (PARTITION BY occupation Order By ename) as rn
  from occupations
  group by ename,occupation)

  select max(Singer) AS Singer,max(Doctor) AS Doctor, max(Actor) AS Actor
  from cte
  where rn=1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/514b2/4/0)**:

```
| Singer | Doctor | Actor |
|--------|--------|-------|
|    Jim |   Anna | Helen |
```

Comment: the result of your query is what I got with mine, the problem was to get all rows, and the post above solved it. Thank you for your assistance, your query is helpful still, and I'll sure learn what it does.

Answer (score 1):

You can also make it dynamic to automatically pick all columns

```
create table #occupations  (ename nvarchar(10), occupation nvarchar(10) )
insert   #occupations
values 
('John','Doctor'),('Mary','Doctor'),('Jack','Doctor'),('Anna','Doctor'),
('Jim','Singer'),('Kate','Singer'),('Helen','Actor'),('Paco','Singer') ;


DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(occupation) 
            FROM #occupations 
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'');

set @query = 'SELECT * FROM #occupations
                    PIVOT
                        (min(ename)  
                FOR occupation IN ('+ @cols +')  
              )AS pp'
exec (@query) 
drop table #occupations
```